# C++ -- Difference between "throw new BadConversion("xxx")" and "throw BadConversion("xxx")"

Tags: c++, exception

```
// http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html
class BadConversion : public std::runtime_error {
 public:
   BadConversion(std::string const& s)
     : std::runtime_error(s)
     { }
 };

 inline std::string stringify(double x)
 {
   std::ostringstream o;
   if (!(o << x))
     throw BadConversion("stringify(double)");
     // throw new BadConversion("stringify(double)");
   return o.str();
 }
```

[Q1] When we throw an exception in the function, what is the difference between throw new ClassName() and throw ClassName()?

[Q2] Which one is better?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[A1] With `throw new`, you'll have to `catch` a pointer. The language doesn't specify in this case who is responsible for deallocation, so you'll have to establish your own convention (typically you'd make the catcher responsible). Without `new`, you'll want to `catch` by reference.

[A2] If you're in a framework that commonly throws pointers, you may want to follow suit. Else, `throw` without `new`. See also the [C++ FAQ, item 17.14](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.14).

Comment: "Your object may get copied when re-thrown." : Not if you use no-expression `throw;` to rethrow like you should.  That is, do not do: `catch (Something& e) { ... throw e; }`

Comment: I am with aschepler here. Throwing e can lead to errors as it may result in slicing of the object. Just calling `throw;` solves that problem and makes sure the correct object continues on its unwind trajectory.

Comment: Also catching a pointer does not mean you are responsible for deleting the object. The problem is that you **can't tell** if you should or should not delete the pointer without knowing the context from where it was thrown.

Comment: @Martin York: you're right for pointers in general, but the OP wants to know if he should use `throw new` in his own code. That construct does make the catcher responsible.

Comment: Unfortunately not. As a maintainer may go in a year latter and throw the address of an object of static storage duration. The problem is **You can't tell**. If the solution was as simple that everything is thrown by new then the problem goes away deleting the object in the catch block is simple and repetitive enough that the compiler could do it (or at least generate warnings if you did not).

Answer (score 1):

`throw new ClassName()` throws pointer to ClassName. You need to `catch (ClassName * pc)`. It's not good idea. If `new` returns null or throws then you have null pointer when you catch or you have double exception.

`throw ClassName()` is usual way to throw an exception.  You need to `catch (const ClassName & pc)`.

Comment: No reason it can't be non-`const`. (Or for that matter, by value rather than by reference...)

Comment: @Billy: Catch by reference, not by value!  Catching by value slices.

Comment: @aschepler: Yes, it slices, and therefore is not a good idea. But it is *possible*.

Answer (score 1):

`throw new BadConversion(”xxx“)` is creating a new object on the heap and throwing a pointer to it.  That object will have to be deleted by the catch block.  I can't think of a good reason why you would want to do that.

The other version is taken care of by RAII, use that.

Comment: +1 for use the non new version, -1 for calling that "RAII" -- there's no resource being managed inside the exception. Total: 0.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: What about the error message string (that's a resource).

Comment: @Martin York: Why does there need to be such a string? A simple character literal inside the exception does the job just fine and requires no managment. (And for that matter, your exception class need not derive from `std::exception`)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: But the above code is derived from std::runtime_error thus it manages a message resource.

Comment: @Martin: In the code above `string` is the object doing RAII, not the exception.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Seriously Billy. You just counteracted your own argument that RAII is not being used by saying it is. Where do you think the exception stores the message?

Comment: @Martin: Errr, no, I did not. The exception is not an RAII class, because it does not manage resources. String is an RAII class, because it does. More to the point, RAII done by the string class would still be being done if the exception was dynamically allocated, and therefore it could not distinguish the version catching by pointer from the version catching by reference on this point.

Answer (score 1):

Within your code base you should choose one method and stick to it for consistency.

If some of your code throws pointers and other libraries throws objects then your catch clauses may get a bit convoluted as you may need catches for both pointers and objects of the same type.

I personally prefer to throw objects rather than pointers (the main reason I choose this rather than pointers is that it mimics the standard library). Though it is quite feasible to throw pointers the question of ownership rears its ugly head. Who (if anybody) is responsible for deleting the pointer?